# when push notification clicked its not redirecting to desired class when app is closed in firebase

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi friends i am getting crazy from last few days i don't know why it happening please help.

I am using the firebase push notification in my app, where from the backend to my app. Problem is that when the push notification is clicked when app is open, it redirects to the correct class. But when the push notification comes when app is closed, it goes to main class only.

FireBase.class

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Constant.l(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("mtype")) {
            Constant.l(String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData()));
            sendNotification(getApplicationContext(), remoteMessage.getData().get("message"), remoteMessage.getData().get("id"), remoteMessage.getData().get("type"), remoteMessage.getData().get("username"), remoteMessage.getData().get("mtype"));
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(Context context, String messageBody, String sid, String type, String username, String mtype) {
        if (Session.isLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())) {
            switch (mtype) {
                case "single":
                    Intent chathis = new Intent(ChatHistory.BroadCastAction);
                    chathis.putExtra("msg", messageBody);
                    chathis.putExtra("type", type);
                    context.sendBroadcast(chathis);
                    intent = new Intent(this, ChatHistory.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("mtype", "single");
                    intent.putExtra("oppusername", username);
                    intent.putExtra("oid", sid);
                    break;
                case "group":
                    Intent grphis = new Intent(Group_History.BroadCastAction);
                    grphis.putExtra("msg", messageBody);
                    grphis.putExtra("sid", sid);
                    grphis.putExtra("type", type);
                    grphis.putExtra("usern", username);
                    context.sendBroadcast(grphis);
                    intent = new Intent(context, Group_History.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("mtype", "single");
                    intent.putExtra("oppusername", username);
                    intent.putExtra("oid", sid);
                    break;
                default:
                    intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    break;
            }
        }
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        try {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Constant.l(e.toString());
        }
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(username.replace("$", ""))
                .setContentText(messageBody.replace("$", " "))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Config.php

```
class PushNotifications {
    //Firebase
    private static $apiKey = 'AAAACmtNrq0:APA91bHFH6KKA3irMMlc99hoJhTASuluM_KyNtyUYmcnWK41QeWxI9EystYFNBRwSNOqLtAB24xZ_bh_0YLugEkFfb94VYmAiJHWOlQgmlQP-4jMQnClE1_mCgnItOgnI2EAnNmQadcrko-oS-iU1eCwNPrsxPRXlQ';

    // Change the above three vriables as per your app.
    public function __construct() {
        //exit('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    // Sends Push notification for Android users
    public function send($data, $reg_id) {
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $message = array(
            "message" => $data['mdesc'],
            "id" => $data['facebook_id'],
            "username" => $data['username'],
            "type" => $data['type'],
            "mtype" => $data['mtype'],
            "profile" =>$data['profile']
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'Authorization:key='.self::$apiKey,
        );

        $fields = array(                    
            'notification' => array("title" => $data['mtitle'], "body" => $data['mdesc'], "sound"=>"default",
            "icon"=>"fcm_push_icon"),   
            'data' => $message, 
            'to' => $reg_id,    
            "priority" => "high",   
            "restricted_package_name"=>""
        );
        return $this->useCurl($url, $headers, json_encode($fields));
    }

    // Curl 
    private function useCurl($url, $headers, $fields = null) {
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        if ($url) {
            // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            if ($fields) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            }

            // Execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);

            return $result;
        }
    }    
}
$push = new PushNotifications();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android, When app is closed then after click on notification it always redirect to launcher activity.

While app is closed and if you got notification from fcm then you have to handle notification in launcher activity. shift intent from launcher to desired class where all notification listed.

Comment: Means when i had redirected to main activity then i have to handle that intent right?

Comment: yes if main activity is your launcher class, then shift intent from main activity  to notification activity.

Comment: try this code in onCreate:

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DesiredActivity.class);
        if (getIntent() != null) {
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                if (bundle.get("message") != null) {
                    String value = bundle.get("message").toString();
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.FROM_NOTIFICATIONS, value);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } 
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I had solved it by removing this line **'notification' => array("title" => $data['mtitle'], "body" => $data['mdesc'], "sound"=>"default",
            "icon"=>"fcm_push_icon")**  from the config.php